# Error when inserting data to postgresql with php

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to insert some data into a table in a PostgreSQL database. I use prepared statements for this purpose like:

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=wind;user=postgres;password=1249;host=localhost;port=5432');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($arrayAddress); $x++) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO geocoding_test (address,googlemaps) VALUES (address=:address, sucUn=:sucUn ) ");
   $stmt->execute(array(address => $arrayAddress[$x], sucUn => $arraySucUnsuc[$x] ));
}
```

...where `arrayAddress` is an array containing all the addresses and `arraySucUnsuc` is an array containing some string.

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
    SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column 'address' does not exist 
    LINE 1: ... INTO geocoding_test (address,googlemaps) VALUES (address=$1... ^
    HINT: There is a column named 'address' in table 'geocoding_test', but it cannot be
    referenced from this part of the query.' in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Wind\predictVdslEligibilityWSLog-20150614\myWebCrawler.php:98
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\Wind\predictVdslEligibilityWSLog-20150614\myWebCrawler.php(98): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
    #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Wind\predictVdslEligibilityWSLog-20150614\myWebCrawler.php on line98
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also this is the definition of my table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE geocoding_test
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    address character varying(600),
    googlemaps character varying(50)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (fieldname1, ...) VALUES (value1, ...)
```

You have

```
... VALUES (address=:address, ...
```

where you're trying to COMPARE (`=`) an existing value `address` against the parameter you're passing. Since this is an `INSERT` query, that `address1` value doesn't exist yet: you can't read from what doesn't exist.

The query should be just

```
.... VALUES(:address, :sucUn)
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how people can make stupid mistakes like this...and spending one hour trying to figure out what's wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mental roadblocks. I've spent HOURS staring at a few lines of code wondering why it won't work, then realizing that I'd put in a `;` to terminate a statement, which is illegal in the particular language I was using.